# Opening different classes by Intent according to the position from the OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, class, listview, click

I want to open different classes when I click on the ListView. I have already created the onItemClickListener and in that I am opening the class but I can open only one class instead of being able to open the class associated to the Item in the List.

There is a parameter called "int position" in the OnItemClickLcisterer but I don't know how to use.

I have so many different Items in my list and I want to Open a particular class from my OnItemClickListener associated to that Item from the List.

Here I am placing what I am doing in my OnItemClickListener:

nameOfStates.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(StateSelection.this, AlaskaZone.class);
                    startActivity(mIntent);

```
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(StateSelection.this, AlabamaZone.class);
                startActivity(myIntent); 

            }
        });
```

There is Item(name) Alaska in my listing that is supposed to open the AlaskaZone Class, likewise the Item(name) Alabama from myh listing is supposed to open the AlabamaZone Class.

How can I do that particularly?

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 1):

Its simple in your listener put switch- case block and use position in that for cases the 0 position reflect the very first item in your list and so on and for every case start different activity

```
nameOfStates.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        { 
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    // Start activity that you want to when 1st item of your list is selected
                    break;

                case 1:
                    // Start activity that you want to when 2nd item of your list is selected
                    break;
            }               
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please show me because I have already tried but couldn't do it. May be I have been making some mistake in my coding.

Answer (score 0):

use the argument `postion` present in the onItemClick method to identify the row which has been clicked, which in turn would help you to identify the state

Comment: @Frieze- Can you please tell me how can I use that position because I have been trying several ways but didn't succeeded.

Comment: david, how do you show the states in the list. I mean you must be using an adapter to populate the list right ? could you share your adapter code so that I may point you where to make the change